# Yammer - forcing to join/follow

Tags: yammer

I am dealing with a problem that I would like to force all the users of a Yammer network to automatically join some groups (like HR) or follow some topics (like newsletters). I haven't been able to find any solutions to this topic that wouldn't require the users to accept the invitation to the group, except the All Network group that is joined automatically. For the force to follow I haven't been able to find anything...

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to force all the users to join some group, other than the All Network group?
2. Is it possible to force all the users to follow some topic?
3. Is it possible to enforce that the users won't be able to leave the group/unfollow the topic?

If anyone would please know any answers it would be super helpful. Thank you all so much in the advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to force all the users to join some group, other than the All Network group?

Yes. You can use the impersonation endpoint to programmatically add users to a group. You'd need to be the network's verified admin to be able to do this. See details [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2015/07/31/yammer-rest-api-how-to-bulk-add-members-to-a-yammer-group/).

> 2. Is it possible to force all the users to follow some topic?

Yes. Using the same impersonation endpoint described above, and by sending a POST request to `https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/subscriptions` with `topic_id` and `target_type = topic` as params. See details [here](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/subscriptions)

> 3. Is it possible to enforce that the users won't be able to leave the group/unfollow the topic?

No.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It looks like what I have been looking for :)